# Echo to all files found from GREP

Tags: linux, bash, grep, echo

I'm having a trouble with my code.
grep looks for files that doesn't have a word 'code'
and I need to add 'doesn't have' as a last line in those files

By logic

```
echo 'doesnt have' >> grep -ril 'code' file/file
```

I'm using -ril to ignore the cases and get file names

Does anyone know how to append a text to each .txt files found from grep searches?

Comment: You are using the wrong option, `-l` will list the files which *do* contain the string. You want upper case `-L`.

Comment: @Aset : You are creating here a file named `grep` containing the text _doesnt have -ril 'code' file/file_ . I don't understand what from your question what you wanted to achieve.

Comment: Agree; code which doesn't do at all what you want and contains weird syntax errors is not a good way to communicate what you do want.

Answer (score 2):

How's this for a novel alternative?

```
echo "doesn't have" |
tee -a $(grep -riL 'code' file/file)
```

I switched to the `-L` option to list the files which do not contain the search string.

This is unfortunately rather brittle in that it assumes your file names do not contain whitespace or other shell metacharacters. This can be fixed at the expense of some complexity (briefly, have `grep` output zero-terminated matches, and read them into an array with `readarray -d ''`. This requires a reasonably recent Bash, and probably GNU `grep`.)

Answer (score 0):

The 'echo' command can append output to a single file, which must be specified by redirecting the standard output. To update multiple files, a loop is needed. The loop iterated over all the files found with 'grep'

```
for file in $(grep -ril 'code' file/file) ; do
    echo 'doesnt have' >> $file
done
```

Comment: Quote `"$file"`.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `while read loop` and `Process Substitution`.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS= read -r files; do
  echo "doesn't have" >> "$files"
done < <(grep -ril 'code' file/file)
```

---

As mentioned by @dibery

```sh
#!/bin/sh

grep -ril 'code' file/file | {
  while IFS= read -r files; do
    echo "doesn't have" >> "$files"
  done
}
```

Comment: Piping `grep` output to the while loop, you can avoid process substitution.